# Why is htmlspecialchars consistently displaying &#34; and &#39; instead of the actual quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, escaping, htmlspecialchars

I have data being processed from a user, that is sanitized and validated, using filter_var() in both cases. It's then stored in the database, and accessed later on a different page of the site. I  escape the output using htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES);

However, if a user enters a single quote or a double quote at any point in their input, it gets displayed as " for double quotes and ' for single quotes. It is also stored in the database as " and '

I need the browser to render the actual quote and not this code.

I've looked everywhere on stackoverflow and I can't seem to find a specific answer to my problem.

**Below is a snippet of some of the data that gets sanitized** - Data is then validated for length,  and whether it's empty or not, and formatting in some cases like postal code.

```
$contact_postal = filter_var($_POST['contact-postal'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$contact_address = filter_var($_POST['contact-address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$contact_person = filter_var($_POST['contact-person'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$contact_person_phone = filter_var($_POST['contact-person-phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$contact_additional_details = filter_var($_POST['contact-additional-details'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

**Here's some of the data that gets retrieved for display**

```
$postal_code = htmlspecialchars(safeDecrypt($row['postal_code'], $enc_key), ENT_QUOTES);

if (!empty($row['address'])) $address = htmlspecialchars(safeDecrypt($row['address'], $enc_key), ENT_QUOTES);

$contact_person = htmlspecialchars($row['contact_person'], ENT_QUOTES);

if (!empty($contact_person) && !empty($contact_person_phone)) $contact_person_phone = htmlspecialchars(safeDecrypt($row['contact_person_phone'], $enc_key), ENT_QUOTES);

$contact_details = htmlentities($row['contact_details'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); //used alternatively to test (but same problem occurs)
```

The safeDecrypt function simply decrypts the data that was previously encrypted. It is highly unlikely that it is the problem, as the ' problem occurs with or without it.

Comment: Looks like it gets escaped twice. FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING and htmlspecialchars do the same thing. Dump the raw data (CLI or view-source to check) at each step and find out.

Comment: @mario I can see in the database, at least for the unencrypted data, that &#39; and &#34; are stored instead of the quotes. Is there something I should be doing differently to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent `htmlspecialchars` from converting `'` or `"` you can use the `ENT_NOQUOTES` flag instead e.g.:

```
$contact_details = htmlentities($row['contact_details'], ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

[htmlspecialchars docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

---

If you're wanting to preserve the quotes when using `filter_var` you can use the `FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES` e.g.

```
$contact_postal = filter_var($_POST['contact-postal'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

[sanitize filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: I still get the same &#39; and &#34;

Comment: @MailCarrier Oh sorry! You mentioned in your question, "*It is also stored in the database as " and '*, so I assumed that it was just the call to `htmlspecialchars` that was the issue. I can see from your most recent comment that this is not the case.

Comment: @MailCarrier You could simply do a string replace for those characters.

Comment: What's really weird is that I tried that, and yet I still get these values, I can't seem to get rid of them. The only solution to remove the codes was to use htmlspecialchars_decode() but obviously that defeats the purpose of encoding the string for display.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to prevent `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ` from also replacing the quotes.

Comment: That solved it, thank you!